# How to use waldboost detector in opencv-3.2 using python

Tags: python-3.x, detection, opencv3.0, object-detection

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
detector=cv2.createWaldBoost()
```

but this code is showing me error

> detector=cv2.createWaldBoost()
>   AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createWaldBoost'

Comment: I dont think it can be used as there are no availbale python wrappers for this

Comment: can please tell how to check whether it is available or not??